# How to write a for loop for printing the all months and days in the month in java?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I am trying to print all months in a year based on user input. Ex: say if someone entered 2004 they would then see a calendar of all 12 months with the days in 2004 in this format:

```
      May 2004
 S  M  T  W  T  F  S
             1  2  3 
 4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 
18 19 20 21 22 23 24 
25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

I've already written the for loop for printing all the months but how do I print all the days in that month? Also the code for the days of the week are able to print as well but I am having trouble printing the days for each month.

```
public class Month {
   private static final String[] MONTHS = {
         "", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
         "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"
   };

   private static final int[] NUMDAYS = {
         0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31
   };

   // Declaring a private variable called month.
   private static int month;
   private int year;

   public Month(int month, int year) {
      // Assigning the value of the parameter month to the instance variable month.
      this.month = month;
      this.year = year;

   }

   public int getYear() {
      return year;
   }

   private boolean isLeapYear() {
      if (year % 400 == 0) {
         return true;
      }
      if (year % 100 == 0) {
         return false;
      }
      return year % 4 == 0;
   }

   private int getNumDays() {
      if (month == 2) {
         if (isLeapYear()) {
            return 29;
         } else {
            return 28;
         }
      } else {
         return NUMDAYS[month];
      }
   }

   private int getStartDOW() {
      int m, y;
      if (month < 3) {
         m = month + 12;
         y = year - 1;
      } else {
         m = month;
         y = year;
      }
      return (13 * (m + 1) / 5 + y + y / 4 - y / 100 + y / 400) % 7;
   }

   private String[] getAllMonths() {
      for (int i = 0; i < MONTHS.length; i++) {
         System.out.println(MONTHS[i]);
      }
      return MONTHS;
   }

   public void printCalendar() {
      String[] mon = getAllMonths();
      System.out.println("       " + MONTHS + " " + year);
      System.out.println(" S  M  T  W  T  F  S");
      int dow = getStartDOW();
      for (int i = 0; i < dow; i++) {
         System.out.print("   ");
      }
      int numdays = getNumDays();
      for (int i = 1; i <= numdays; i++) {
         System.out.printf("%2d ", i);
         if (dow == 6) {
            System.out.println();
            dow = 0;
         } else {
            dow++;
         }
      }
      System.out.println();

   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter year: ");
      int year = s.nextInt();
      Month m = new Month(month, year);
      m.printCalendar();
   }

}
```

Comment: the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package already contains all it's needed in order to avoid to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure we are doing your homework here. If not, please use a Library (e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_date.asp) as already suggested.

My first thought is this:

1. Find the day of the week of January 1st. I don't know if you have an algorithm for that or if you are allowed to use a library for that.
2. Loop through all month.
3. Start each month on the day+1 of previous month and end it after 28, 29, 30 or 31 days.

---

```
array MONTH = January,...
array NUMDAYS = 31,...

num indexLastDayPreviousMonth = calcFor1stJanuary - 1

loop MONTH
    indexLastDayPreviousMonth = printMonth(nameMonth, indexDayPreviousMonth, numOfDaysInMonth)

method printMonth(nameMonth, indexDayPreviousMonth, numOfDaysInMonth)
    print nameMonth
    printDays from indexDayPreviousMonth + 1 for numOfDaysInMonth
    return indexLastDayOfMonth
```

I hope I outlined my idea understandable.

I also would split the code in a Calendar and a Month class. The Calendar has the logic on which day the given year starts and so on. The Month has the logic to print a month.